# populate html table with json values

Tags: php, jquery, json

I have an table.html, data.php and json.csv within the same folder.

data.php is doing `fopen("json.csv","r")` to read from json.csv.

How can I display the json objects as a table within table.html?

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js">
    function display(){
  $.post('data.php',function(data){
     $("#txtJSON").html(data); 
  });
    }

   </script>
   </head>
   <body onload="display()">
   <table id="#jobtable">
   <input type="text" id="txtJSON" />
   </table>
   </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: Have you attempted to write any code for doing this yourself?  If so, please share it and let us know in which way it's not working.

Comment: Is json.csv JSON or CSV? They're two different formats...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

psuedocode

php

```
Take the data read in from doing the fopen.
create a php array (a1)
create a php array (a2)
split it on new lines 
iterate through all of those lines
  clear (a2)
  split the current line on commas (or w/e separator)
    insert each element into a2
  insert a2 into a1

return a json_encode(a1)
```

html

```
do a jQuery.parseJSON(returned data from php) http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/
iterate through the datastructure adding a new html row for every row in the structure...
```

Answer (score 0):

you can convert json.csv output in a php array and merge data.php & table.html in one php file in that file make a html table with `foreach`

Answer (score 0):

You will be better off if you use JavaScript for any extensive DOM manipulation. More specifically, [jQuery plugin JSON-to-table](https://github.com/anuary/jquery-json-to-table) can do exactly what you want.